# java expanding panels on button click event

Tags: java

I have a JFrame that has three panels:

```
======================================
|                                    |
|                                    |
|          Green Panel               |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
======================================
|          Blue Panel                |
|                                    |
======================================
|      Button1       Button2         |
|                                    |
======================================
```

When I click on Button1, I want to hide the Blue Panel and disable Button1.   When I click on Button2, I want to display the Blue Panel and disable Button2.

I know that I can use setVisible(boolean) to show and hide components.

My question is, when I hide the Blue Panel, how do I make the Green panel expand and take up the space that was formerly occupied by the Blue Panel?  Conversely, when I click on Button2, I want the Blue panel to re-appear and the Green panel go back to the previous size?

Is something like this possible without hard-coding the sizes of the Panels since I may want to increase the window size.

Comment: Do some research into CardLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does what you need using `BorderLayout`.

It is not pretty but works.

```
public class TESTMAIN extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TESTMAIN frame = new TESTMAIN();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TESTMAIN() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
        greenPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel.add(greenPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel.add(bluePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton button1 = new JButton("New button");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                bluePanel.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        panel_1.add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("New button");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bluePanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        panel_1.add(button2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getHeight() method of JPanel as follow

```
JPanel pnlGreen = new JPanel();
JPanel pnlRed = new JPanel();

if(e.getSource() == btnOne){
   pnlRed.setHeight(pnlRed.getHeight()+pnlGreen.getHeight());
   //Panel and Button show/hide code
}
else if(e.getSource() == btnTwo){
   pnlGreen.setHeight(pnlRed.getHeight()+pnlGreen.getHeight());
   //Panel and Button show/hide code
}

if you want to apply this on window resize then add this code to window minimize and maximize event
```

Comment: Right up to the moment the layout is revalidated